# Push and forms in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing this problem, I have a form which is below, some comments which are presented as a list block quote in my page. What I want to do is to live preview what I am writing in the 3 fields, two are required above my form aligned with the other comments in the same format. The comments consist of Name, Rating, Comment and date. All these have to be done with Angular Js. The problems I face is that in my `app.js` file I have 4 controllers and what I write in one field which is in `DishCommentController` can't be put in the array which is in `DishDetailController`. Also I don't know how to set the current date.

My html code in form is this:

```
<div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1" ng-controller="DishCommentController">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li>

                      <blockquote>

                        <p><span ng-show="commentForm.$valid && !commentForm.$pristine">{{ userFeedback.userComment }}</span></p>

<footer>{{userFeedback.userName}}</footer>

                      </blockquote>    
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <form class="form-horizontal" name="commentForm"
                    ng-submit="submitComment()" novalidate>
                <!--task1-creating the form-->

                <div class="form-group" 
                     ng-class="{ 'has-error' : commentForm.firstname.$error.required && !commentForm.firstname.$pristine }"><!-- Task2:Angular validation with red color with the first control:"nameofForm.nameofField.$error.required" and the second control:"!nameofForm.nameofField.$pristine if user touched the form but didn't type anything. --> 
                    <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your Name</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-10">

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter Your Name" 
                           ng-model="userFeedback.userName" required> <!--bind the value of the input field to a variable with ng-model-->

                        <span ng-show="commentForm.firstname.$error.required && !commentForm.firstname.$pristine" class="help-block">Name field is required.</span> <!-- here we show the message under the field when we have error in our field -->

                    </div>

                </div>

                 <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="stars" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Number of Stars</label>

                     <div class="col-sm-10">

                        <label class="radio-inline">

                            <input type="radio" name="stars" id="stars" value="option1" ng-model="userFeedback.userRating">1</label>

                        <label class="radio-inline">

                            <input type="radio" name="stars" id="stars" value="option2" ng-model="userFeedback.userRating">2</label>

 <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="stars" id="stars" value="option3" ng-model="userFeedback.userRating">3</label>

<label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="stars" id="stars" value="option4" ng-model="userFeedback.userRating">4</label>

<label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="stars" id="stars" value="option5" ng-model="userFeedback.userRating" ng-checked="true">5</label>

</div>

</div>

<div class="form-group"
                     ng-class="{'has-error' : commentForm.userComments.$error.required && !commentForm.userComments.$pristine}"><!-- Angular validation with red color with the first control:"nameofForm.nameofField.$error.required" and the second control:"!nameofForm.nameofField.$pristine if user touched the form but didn't type anything. --> 


<label for="userComments" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your Comments</label>

<div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="userComments" name="userComments" rows="12" ng-model="userFeedback.userComment" required></textarea>

                        <span ng-show="commentForm.userComments.$error.required && !commentForm.userComments.$pristine" class="help-block">Comment field is required.</span> <!-- here we show the message under the field when we have error in our field -->

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="commentForm.$invalid">Submit Comment</button><!--submit button is disabled through ng-disabled until user enter all the required fields-->
                    </div>

                </div>
            </form><!-- end of task1 -->
        </div>
```

and in my `app.js` the two controllers are these:

```
 .controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        var dish={
                      name:'Uthapizza',
                      image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                      category: 'mains', 
                      label:'Hot',
                      price:'4.99',
                      description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                       comments: [
                           {
                               rating:5,
                               comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                               author:"John Lemon",
                               date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                               author:"Paul McVites",
                               date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:3,
                               comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                               author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                               date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                               author:"Ringo Starry",
                               date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:2,
                               comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                               author:"25 Cent",
                               date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           }

                       ]
                };

        $scope.dish = dish;

    }])


.controller('DishCommentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

$scope.userFeedback = {userName:"",userComment:""};

 $scope.submitComment = function () {
     //Step 2: This is how you record the date
         $scope.userFeedback.userComment = new Date().toISOString();

      // Step 3: Push your comment into the dish's comment array
          console.log("so far correct");

          $scope.dish.comments.push($scope.userFeedback.userComments);

          console.log("so far correct");

     //Step 4: reset your form to pristine
    $scope.userFeedback.userName="";

    $scope.userFeedback.userComment="";

    $scope.commentForm.$setPristine();

    console.log("correct");


     //Step 5: reset your JavaScript object that holds your comment
      $scope.userFeedback = {userName:"",userComment:""};

      console.log("correct-end");
 }


}]);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Could you please fix the code formatting? Also, why ` can't be put in the array which is in DishDetailController`? (I'm sorry, this is out of my expertise but I guess you get an error? What is it then?). `Also i don't know how to set the current date.` - it's a different question altogether, and it probably has an answer somewhere in the BlogoSphere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i figured out the solution....I didn't do nesting in my controllers that's why i couldn't get the results i want......However,the formatting of the code is fixed?I am new so i want to know for future questions or answers...Thanks a lot

Comment: yes, the new formatting looks great, thanks. For the future this is a good reference ;) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask